# Can't access my SVN repository

Tags: tortoisesvn, svn

I've used the following guide (up to step 5) to setup SVN on my personal server:
http://blog.loadbalancer.org/how-to-setup-subversion/

Now I'm using TortoiseSVN on my client machine to import my work into the server. I've tried the URL svn://www.*mysite*.com/repos/project_name , but it gives me a "no repository found" error, even though I'm sure the SVN daemon is running.

My repository is setup under /home/svn/repos/project_name

Do you have any idea what I could be doing wrong? I've never done this before so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot it.

Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, svn repositories can be found here:

*svn://www.mysite.com/repo_name*

...and svn over ssh repositories here:

*svn://www.mysite.com/path-to-repos/repo_name*

Comment: Oh ok. I got an error though saying "/home/svn/repos/project_name/conf/svnserve.conf:12: Option expected". I've checked the file and I found an uncommented "anon-acess = none" there. Why is it giving an error? seems alright to me.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with this error, but you may check the logs and try to run in verbose mode perhaps.

Comment: Just found a space preceding all of the options, which produced the error. Once I removed those spaces, everything was working fine. Thanks!